# How does the compiler handle Main when instantiating own class

Tags: java, compiler-construction, static, jvm, program-entry-point

EDIT: For clarification:

Create a new class containing static main. Instantiate the same class during the main method. What does the JVM do when it arrives at that main method line of code as it is instantiating it?

(How does the JVM know to "skip over" the static main() method in the following code during the while loop)

I'm asking because I can't see any benefit to put static main into a class that you intend to instantiate, it seems much better to only ever put static main into a "launcher" class, built solely for the purpose of launching the application..

Confusing for the dog class:

```
public class Dog {
    private int height;

    public static void main (String[] args) { // <---- What does the JVM do when it reaches here during the object instantiation?
        int i = 0;
        Dog [] dogArray = new Dog[20];
        while (i < 20){
             dogArray[i] = new Dog(); // Instantiate knew class
             dogArray[i].height = i*10; //whatever
             i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Surely it is always better to create two classes, in this case:

```
public class Dog {
    private int height;

    getHeight{//etc...}
    setHeight{//etc...}
}

public class launchApplication{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    Dog [] dogArray = new Dog[20];
    while (i < 20){
         dogArray[i] = new Dog(); // Instantiate knew class
         dogArray[i].setHeight = i*10; //whatever
         i++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think a `main` method is or does? Why do you think so?

Comment: I think its what the JVM looks for to start the application - and what to do next once it finds it. Which is why it seems random to just stick the main method inside a class that has other functionality, it would be clearer OO to give the main it's own "launcher" class, and keep the other classes as pure Object blueprints.

Comment: The compiler doesn't 'skip over the static main() method in the following code during the while loop'. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the JVM just executes all the code it finds in a class. That's not how Java works.

Comment: @EJP I should have said how does the JVM handle the main (not how does the compiler) - When creating a new object of the Dog class, how does the JVM iterate through the Dog Class? What is it using and what is it ignoring inside that class?

Comment: @chrylis - hence my question how does it work? How does the JVM iterate through that class to create the object?

Comment: ...it *doesn't* "iterate" through it.

Comment: ....what _does_ it do?

Comment: It loads the symbol table and then invokes the code the methods in the table point to. If you're wanting to get into the low-level details, just read the JVM Specification; it's not really going to get any easier than that.

Comment: Thanks thats the direction I was looking for, I'll check out the JVM spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer I was looking for (and the question I was trying to ask) was actually how the JVM goes about bootstrapping and invoking main. It is native code that first starts the JVM and the main method is called using STATIC so as to avoid having to somehow (externally) create an object first, and then call the main method from that object.

The confusion I had over why the main method was "ignored" was a misunderstanding of how that main method is called - it is called explicitly by the JVM **during it's launch**, and this, is the JAVA convention - The JVM is built and designed this way, it is a dedicated method.

So in my example, main, being a method, is not called during each instantiation of the class that main belongs to (because methods are not implicitly called during instantiation), I was under the impression that main was somehow automatically called whenever a class is instantiated by virtue of it being "the java main method" - as if it had a hook to be called. The key was in grasping STATIC and how the JVM loads the Main method without having it's enclosing class instantiated first. This essentially is the transition from the JVM (including native) bootstrap procedural process into the more "purer" object oriented capability of the running JAVA application.

Hope that makes sense, and hope it might help someone clarify something.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * The constructor
     */
    public Test() {
        System.out.println("The is the constrcutor");
    }

    /**
     * The main method
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is main");

        new Test();
        new Test();
        new Test();
    }

    /**
     * A static method
     */
    public static void count() {
        System.out.println("This is a static method");
    }

    /**
     * A static block
     */
    static {
        System.out.println("This is the static block");
    }
}
```

> **Output :**
>
> This is the static block
>
> This is main
>
> The is the constrcutor
>
> The is the constrcutor
>
> The is the constrcutor

Run the above code and you ll get a better idea on this.

The `main` method is called by the jvm, when you run the program. Why should it be called when you instantiate the `Test` class.

When you instantiate a class, first the static block will be executed. And it ll be for the first instantiateation, not for all. (look at the output).

Then the constructor ll be called.

If you look at the output, no static method is called. Static methods ll be called only when they are called. This is why `count()` is not executing in this case. `main` method is called by JVM for once, to start the program, however after that it's still a regular static method of the class, which won't excecute util it's called.

Comment: Is that not just calling the Test method of the class? If you think of the class as the blueprint for objects it seems messy to have the main inside of a random class. It feels like much better OO to create a "class" for the sole purpose of starting the app, in which you can then create your Test class and run the test methods.

Comment: `Test()` here , is the `constructor` of class `Test` here. No matter you write it or not, it ll always be called when you instantiate an object.

And yes, it is always better to leave the class that has `main` alone, just for calls and write `POJO` classes and do everything clean.

But to answer your question, object creation does not call `main`

Comment: thanks, so essentially the JVM ignores the main method when instantiating the object if that class happens to contain a main method? Is there anything else it ignores?

Comment: @LeonKowalski nothing is ignored here, to prove it, just create a class with some static methods and instantiate the class, you ll see the static methods won't be called, just like the `count()` method in my code.

Comment: Im confused because in my example during the while loop when each new Dog object is instantiated, the JVM does not run the static main method again - Yet when launching the class for the first time, it does. So how does the JVM determine when to use main and when not to? Am I not making sense here?

Comment: Well, jvm searches the `main` method from the class which has the same name as of the `.java` source file that you are running.

For example : If you class name is `Dog` and it contains the `main` method, your source file must be `Dog.java`. This is how jvm determines which `main` method to call. And this is why, in java class name and file name must be same.

Hope it helped you understand things better :)

Comment: @LeonKowalski if the answer helped you, please go vote it or mark it as answer, and if did not please vote it down. Thanks :)

Comment: The thing is I know that works that way, but I'm trying to understand *how* is works that way, step by step, to improve my understanding of the JVM.. Thanks for you time I've up voted your answer - but it still doesn't actually answer the question of how the JVM goes through the class..